# Is there a VBA function or formula to group results by ID number?

Tags: excel, vba

sheet2 has:

```
123, thomas
123, gordon
123, smith
334, joey
334, nancy
3452, angela
3452, liza
```

Result that I want is:

```
123, thomas, gordon, smith
334, joey, nancy
3452, angela, liza
```

Is there an easy way to do this with a formula? If not, how can I do this with VBA?

Comment: What have you tried? If nothing then this will get you started :) http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1811921

Comment: sweeeeeeeeet you gave me the answer

Comment: @SiddharthRout please make that the answer and ill mark it right

Comment: That's OK :) I just gave you a link which I don't think deserves to be considered as an answer ;) Are you aware that you can post your own answer and you can accept it? In fact it is highly encouraged ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little VBA function (fine-tuning required)

```
Function GetCSV(r As Range, v As Integer) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim s As String
    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        If r.Cells(i, 1) = v Then
            s = s & ", " & r.Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    GetCSV = v & s
End Function
```

Sample usage (assuming that A1: B14 is your data range)

```
=GetCSV(A1:B14,A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste your example starting columns in range ("A1"), paste below code in a module and run. 
I'm going home, up to you to do the formatting and to check whether you like it or not!

```
Sub Test()

Dim rRange                  As Range
Dim iRange                  As Integer
Dim rRange_Final            As Range
Dim sString                 As String
Dim iPosition               As Integer
Dim sID                     As Integer
Dim sName                   As String

Dim sCheck                  As String
Dim iCnt                    As Integer
Dim iCntB                   As Integer
Dim iCntC                   As Integer
Dim iCntD                   As Integer
Dim vArray()                As Variant
Dim vArray_Dest()           As Variant
Dim vArray_Final()          As Variant
Dim bCheck                  As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set range dynamically and load data into an array
Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
iRange = rRange.Rows.Count
ReDim vArray(1 To iRange)
ReDim vArray_Dest(1 To iRange, 1 To 3)
vArray = rRange

'Split based on comma and load into a two dimensional array
For iCnt = 1 To iRange
    sString = Trim(vArray(iCnt, 1))
    iPosition = InStr(1, sString, ",") + 1
    sID = Trim(Left(sString, Len(sString) - (Len(sString) - iPosition)))
    sName = Trim(Mid(sString, iPosition, Len(sString) - iPosition))
    vArray_Dest(iCnt, 1) = sID
    vArray_Dest(iCnt, 2) = sName
Next iCnt

iCnt = 0
iCntC = 0

'Loop through the newly created array, assign ID
For iCnt = 1 To iRange
    sCheck = vArray_Dest(iCnt, 1)
    If vArray_Dest(iCnt, 3) = Empty Then
        iCntC = iCntC + 1
        ReDim Preserve vArray_Final(1 To iCntC)
        For iCntB = 1 To iRange
            If sCheck = vArray_Dest(iCntB, 1) Then
                vArray_Dest(iCntB, 3) = iCntC
            End If
        Next iCntB
    End If
Next iCnt

'Loop through the array while building string in separate array
iCnt = 0
iCntB = 0

For iCnt = 1 To iCntC
    bCheck = False
    For iCntB = 1 To iRange
        If vArray_Dest(iCntB, 3) = iCnt And bCheck = False Then
            vArray_Final(iCnt) = vArray_Dest(iCntB, 1) & ", " & vArray_Dest(iCntB, 2)
            bCheck = True
        ElseIf vArray_Dest(iCntB, 3) = iCnt And bCheck = True Then
            vArray_Final(iCnt) = vArray_Final(iCnt) & ", " & vArray_Dest(iCntB, 2)
        End If
    Next iCntB
Next iCnt

iCnt = 0

'Fill in range
For iCnt = 1 To iCntC
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iCnt, 3).Value = vArray_Final(iCnt)
Next iCnt

End Sub
```